# How do I properly use NSUserDefaults Class to bypass a View?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I have a project in xcode that uses storyboards. The first view that loads is an "accept terms and conditions" view in which the user must click an accept button to proceed. After clicking it, it segues to the next view. After the user clicks accept the first time the program launches, I never want them to see that view again - I want it to go straight to the next view.  I have some code but its not working.  Here is what I have exactly:

In app delegate: (inside applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions)

```
if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"TermsAccepted"]!=YES)
{
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:NO forKey:@"TermsAccepted"];
}
```

Inside the accept terms and conditions view implementation: (viewDidLoad)

```
 if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"TermsAccepted"]){
    [self.navigationController pushViewController: self animated:YES];
    //I want it to go to the next screen
}
    else {
        //I want to show this screen, but I don't know what goes here
}
```

Also Inside the accept terms and conditions view implementation (in the accept button)

```
 - (IBAction)acceptButton:(id)sender {
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"TermsAccepted"];
}
```

I run it and get the error: 'Pushing the same view controller instance more than once is not supported'.  How do I fix this?

Comment: Your first code snippet doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you want to have the next view controller, the one you always want to show, be the root view controller of your window. In that controller's viewDidLoad method, put your if clause to show the accept terms and conditions controller -- you can show that one using presentModalViewController.  The if clase can be like this:

```
If([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] BoolForKey:@"TermsAccepted"] !=YES) {
    // instantiate your terms and conditions controller here
    // present the controller
}
```

Then, in the method where you dismiss the terms and conditions controller, set the value of that key to YES.

Answer (score 1):

1. In your first code snippet, you basically say "if TermsAccepted is not YES (so it is NO), then set it to NO. This does not make sense
2. In your 2nd code snippet, you wrote `[self.navigationController pushViewController:self animated:YES];`. So basically you ask the current `UIViewController` (`self`) to push itself on its own navigationController… which does not make sense either.

That's why you have this error. You try to push the current viewController `self` whereas it is already on screen in your navigationController. So you try to push the same instance (`self`) twice on the same navigationController.

You obviously meant to push another viewController (probably an instance of a `TermsAndConditionViewController` or something that shows the terms and conditions of your app) on the navigation controller, and not the current viewController itself, which doesn't make sense.

Comment: Well, I gathered this code from some answers I already received on here, but I THINK that first line is trying to say when the app launches, set the BOOL to NO only if it is already NO (which would only happen if the accept button had never been clicked). Then, if it gets reset to YES later when the accept button is clicked, it won't be overwritten. Maybe there is a better way to do this. Otherwise, thanks for the info about the view controller, I was obviously thinking about it completely incorrectly.